# How to change width of generated images from amazon using php or javascript string replace

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am working on an amazon page and have come into a dilemma. I am using the easyazon wordpress plugin for amazon associate linking. I'v been working my way through the plugin and have managed to change a few things to my liking. One of my dilemmas is the image size that it generates from amazon.

For the img tag in the html, this is what the plugin produces.

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BMJ2MawrL._SL160_.jpg
```

With amazon image, if you change the SL160 to a different number, it changes to width of the image.

For example. This >

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BMJ2MawrL._SL160_.jpg
```

Will pull in the image at 160 pixel width.

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BMJ2MawrL._SL300_.jpg
```

Will pull in the image at 300px width.

What I need to do is to be able to somehow when the page is generating / generated, change the text "SL160" to "SL300" on all linked images on the page. (A different number of my choice) so a larger image is shown on the page.

What would be the best way to handle this? And most efficient? Im drawing a blank as in how I could handle this.

I've looked in the plugin and there is no where to change any setting to pull in a larger amazon image. The only way I see to do this would be to have either php or jaavscript change all SL160 text strings on the page so SL300 before the page renders. I'm guessing that if it's done after the page renders, that would be horribly slow. I'm Lost.

```
<div class="easyazon-block-image-container">
        <?php printf('<a %s><img %s /></a>', easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), easyazon_collapse_attributes($image_atts)); ?>
    </div>
```

Produces >

```
<img alt="xxx" class="xxx" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BMJ2MawrL._SL160_.jpg">
```

Comment: Where is that text contained, inside a div or an html attribute ?

Comment: Why don't you change it in the plugin? That would seem most logical.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I've looked and can't find anywhere where any settings are pulled in to explicitly say "160px"

Comment: I edited the original post if it will help any

Comment: Still, what do you want to change ? Replacing text and attributes in js is pretty much straight forward and won't be terribly slow unless you run on a potato and there's a lot of changes.

Comment: Sorry new to all this, have a solid understanding of html and css, still learning javascript. I would like to replace all instances of SL160 on the page and replace it with SL300. How would i go about this efficiently?

Comment: Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqynzedn/) if it can help.